# Mono - Command not found

Tags: linux, mono, centos

I'm running `mono 2.10` on `CentOS 5.5` with `Apache 2`. I've installed it already, and am running a `WCF service` on it currently.

But I can't do `mono -V` or `mono program.exe`, which makes me think I installed it incorrectly. The mono binary is in my `/opt/mono/bin/` folder.

What can I do?

Comment: Is `/opt/mono/bin` present in `$PATH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `/opt/mono/bin/mono --version`